# Finding volume of the intersection of two cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration

Two horizontal circular cylinders both have radius a, and
their axes intersect at right angles. Find the volume of their
solid of intersection(where a = 1).
Is it clear to you that each horizontal cross section of the
solid is a square?

I know that this should be found by using integral.But I cannot find the borders and the function that I should integrate( Please do not ask for my way of solving as I could not solve it)

Comment: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~Tom.Kiffe/calc3/newcylinder/2cylinder.html

Comment: @Arif-Rustamov Here's the solution on [WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html) $V=\frac{16*r^3}{3}$